# How to calculate the square root of a special matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, covariance, trace

I have met a question to calculate the square root of a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{s+1}$.

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{11}^{2} & \sigma_{11}^{1/2}\Sigma_{1S}\Sigma_{SS}^{1/2}\\
\sigma_{11}^{1/2}\Sigma_{SS}^{1/2}\Sigma_{S1} & \Sigma_{SS}^{2}
\end{array}\right)^{1/2},$$

where, $\sigma_{11}\in \mathbb{R},\Sigma_{1S}\in \mathbb{R}^{1*s},\Sigma_{S1}=\Sigma_{1S}^T, \Sigma_{SS}\in \mathbb{R}^{s*s}$ come from a covariance matrix
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{1S}\\
\Sigma_{S1} & \Sigma_{SS}
\end{array}\right).$$
Can we directly write down the square root of $A^2$?

Or can we find the eigenvalues' relationship(or trace's relationship) between A and B?